# Inkscape: reset first node

Tags: inkscape

Is there a command in Inkscape to reset the first node of a path to another of its nodes ?

For instance, having these coordinates (2593.486319,54.4063) as the first node of this path:

```
m 0,0 261.98828,-890.8828 -299.999999,-900 2593.486319,54.4063 -253.9941,850.09565 264.3594,870.83005 z
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to open the path between the node you want to become the start node , and the node before it (click on segment between the nodes, Alt + Backspace), and then close it again (Alt + J).

Take into account path direction (enable display of path direction in the node tool's tool control bar, or duplicate the path, then use Extensions > Visualize Path > Number Nodes to see the numbers) for this.

[image: Change start node of a path in Inkscape]